# Setting values from a HashMap with multiple values for 1 key in a listview

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have created the following HashMap of type `HashMap<String, List<String>>`, and am adding values to it as follows:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    values.add(value1);
    values.add(value2);
    hm.put(key, values);
}
```

I want to retrieve the data, parse it into a ListAdapter and then into a ListView. This is the xml for the listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and the xml for the list items:

```
 <!-- for the key value -->
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />


    <!-- For Value 1 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

      <!-- For Value 2 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

How do I retrieve the data from the hashMap, put it in a ListAdapter and then set it to the ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, hm , R.layout.listplaceholder, new String[] { "value1",
                "value2" }, new int[] { R.id.value1, R.id.name});
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`listplaceholder` is my xml. So please change that.

You can also follow this [tutorial](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261990/hashmap-values-not-being-appended-to-listview