# HashMap values not being appended to ListView

Tags: java, android, dictionary, hashmap

i'm trying to retrieve data from a hashmap with multiple values for 1 key and set it to a listview,but instead of setting the values
into the listview and displaying  the listview,all that is displayed is the array(without the key).
The code is as follows:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    //hashmap of type  `HashMap<String, List<String>>`
    HashMap<String, List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        values.add(value1);
        values.add(value2);
        hm.put(key, values);
    }
```

and to retrieve the values and put in a listview

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivitty.this,  Arrays.asList(hm),
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { key,
                                value1,value2},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.value1,R.id.value2 });
                // updating listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

an example is where the key=1,value2=2 and value3=3,it will display the an array that looks like [2,3].
how do i get it to display the lisview and add the key too?

Comment: @Reimeus,thought its added in hm.put(key, values);

Comment: @Reimeus,yeah that added the key.But still instead of displaying the lsitview,it displays the array.

Comment: @Reimeus an example would suffice,really scratched my head on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleAdapters Consturctor states as it's second parameter:

> data: A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row in
>   the list. The Maps contain the data for each row, and should include
>   all the entries specified in "from"

but `HashMap<String, List<String>>` hm is a map of lists. So like `List<Map<String,String>> hm` would be the datatype you probably need.

Here is the edited source:

```
 ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            List<Map<String,String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            Map<String,String> mapPerRow;
            for (int i = 0; i < rowNumbers; i++) {
                mapPerRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mapPerRow.put("column1", value1);
                mapPerRow.put("column2", value2);

                mapList.add(mapPerRow);
            }


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivitty.this,  mapList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "column1", "colum2"},
                    new int[] { R.id.value1,R.id.value2 });
            // updating listview
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't get why you want the key in it (just add Strings to the map if you need more)?